# When I post form into database, ids are passed instead of names. In the front end everything works fine

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Here I am creating a dynamic conditional drop-down list using Java script and Ajax.

PHP: Add.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Data</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
//including the database connection file
include_once("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {   
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['name']);
    $department = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['department']);
    $type = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['type']);
    $priority = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['priority']);
    $totalcredit = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['totalcredit']);
    $reqdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['reqdate']);
    $notes = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['notes']);
        
    // checking empty fields
    if(empty($name) || empty($department) || empty($type) || empty($priority) || empty($totalcredit) || empty($reqdate) || empty($notes)){
                
        if(empty($name)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Name of Request field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }
        
        if(empty($department)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Requested department is empty.</font><br/>";
        }
        
        if(empty($type)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Type of request field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }
        
        if(empty($priority)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Precedence field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($totalcredit)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Total Credit field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($reqdate)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Requested Date field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($notes)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Notes field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }

        //link to the previous page
        echo "<br/><a href='javascript:self.history.back();'>Go Back</a>";
    } 
    else { 
        // if all the fields are filled (not empty) 
            
        //insert data to database   
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO creditDetails(`Name`, `Department`, `Type`, `Priority`, `TotalCredit`, `ReqDate`, `Notes`) VALUES ('$name', '$department', '$type', '$priority', '$totalcredit', '$reqdate', '$notes')");
        //display success message
        echo "<font color='green'>Data added successfully.";
        echo "<br/><a href='index.php'>View Result</a>";
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML: add.html

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Add Data</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        <br/><br/>
    
        <form action="add.php" method="post" name="form1">
            <table width="25%" border="0">
                <tr> 
                    <td>Name of the Request</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td>Dep</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="department"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td>Type of Request</td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="type" id="type">
                        <option value="">Select type</option>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Degree of Precedence</td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="priority" id="priority">
                        <option value="">Select precedence level</option>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td>Total for order</td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="totalcredit" id="totalcredits">
                        <option value="">Select credits</option>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td>Date of Request</td>
                    <td><input type="date" name="reqdate"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td>Notes</td>
                    <td><textarea type="text" name="notes"> </textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

load_json_data('type');

function load_json_data(id, parent_id)
{
 var html_code = '';
 $.getJSON('options.json', function(data){

  html_code += '<option value="">Select '+id+'</option>';
  $.each(data, function(key, value){
   if(id == 'type')
   {
    if(value.parent_id == '0')
    {
        html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
    }
   }
   else
   {
    if(value.parent_id == parent_id)
    {
        html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
    }
   }
  });
  $('#'+id).html(html_code);
 });

}

$(document).on('change', '#type', function(){
 var type_id = $(this).val();
 if(type_id != '')
 {
  load_json_data('priority', type_id);
 }
 else
 {
  $('#priority').html('<option value="">Degree of Precedence</option>');
  $('#totalcredit').html('<option value="">Total Credits used for order</option>');
 }
});
$(document).on('change', '#priority', function(){
 var priority_id = $(this).val();
 if(priority_id != '')
 {
  load_json_data('totalcredits', priority_id);
 }
 else
 {
  $('#totalcredit').html('<option value="">Total Credits used for order</option>');
 }
});
});
```

JSON DATA:

```json
    [
        {
         "id":"1",
         "name":"New Image",
         "parent_id":"0"
        }, 
        {
         "id":"2",
         "name":"Archive Image",
         "parent_id":"0"
        }, 
        {
        "id":"3",
        "name":"Map",
        "parent_id":"0"
        },
        {
        "id":"4",
        "name":"Agreed and Changed Image",
        "parent_id":"0"
        },  
        {
         "id":"5",
         "name":"Standard",
         "parent_id":"1"
        }, 
        {
         "id":"6",
         "name":"priority",
         "parent_id":"1"
        }, 
        {
         "id":"7",
         "name":"Urgent",
         "parent_id":"1"
        }, 
        {
         "id":"8",
         "name":"Dedicated",
         "parent_id":"1"
        }, 
        {
         "id":"9",
         "name":"DT",
         "parent_id":"1"
        }, 
        {
         "id":"10",
         "name":"bus Archive",
         "parent_id":"2"
        }, 
        {
         "id":"11",
         "name":"AS Archive",
         "parent_id":"2"
        }, 
        {
         "id":"12",
         "name":"None",
         "parent_id":"3"
        }, 
        {
         "id":"13",
         "name":"None",
         "parent_id":"4"
        },
        {
        "id":"14",
        "name":"1",
        "parent_id":"5"
        },
        {
        "id":"15",
        "name":"2",
        "parent_id":"6"
        },
        {
        "id":"16",
        "name":"3",
        "parent_id":"7"
        },
        {
        "id":"17",
        "name":"4",
        "parent_id":"8"
        },
        {
        "id":"18",
        "name":"5.5",
        "parent_id":"9"
        },
        {
        "id":"19",
        "name":"11",
        "parent_id":"9"
        },
        {
        "id":"20",
        "name":"16.5",
        "parent_id":"9"
        },
        {
        "id":"21",
        "name":"22",
        "parent_id":"9"
        },
        {
        "id":"22",
        "name":"27.5",
        "parent_id":"9"
        },
        {
        "id":"23",
        "name":"33",
        "parent_id":"9"
        },
        {
        "id":"24",
        "name":"38.5",
        "parent_id":"9"
        },
        {
        "id":"25",
        "name":"44",
        "parent_id":"9"
        },
        {
        "id":"26",
        "name":"49.5",
        "parent_id":"9"
        },
        {
        "id":"27",
        "name":"55",
        "parent_id":"9"
        },
        {
        "id":"28",
        "name":"0",
        "parent_id":"10"
        },
        {
        "id":"29",
        "name":"0",
        "parent_id":"11"
        },
        {
        "id":"30",
        "name":"0",
        "parent_id":"12"
        },
        {
        "id":"27",
        "name":"0",
        "parent_id":"13"
        }
       ]
```

The Above script works but when posting the form by submit, the ids' are posted into the database instead of the names'

for eg.

```json
{
 "id":"10",
 "name":"bus Archive",
 "parent_id":"2"
}
```

from the above json data,
**10** is saved **into database instead of** **bus Archive**

Comment: You are showing the frontend code, which appears to work and not the backend code where the problem lies

Comment: Please show the backend code, it's where the problem resides

Comment: @domenikk please take a look

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your JS function to this:

```js
function load_json_data(id, parent_id) {
    var html_code = "";
    $.getJSON("options.json", function (data) {
      html_code += '<option value="">Select ' + id + "</option>";
      $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        if (id == "type") {
          if (value.parent_id == "0") {
            html_code +=
              '<option value="' + value.name + '">' + value.name + "</option>";
          }
        } else {
          if (value.parent_id == parent_id) {
            html_code +=
              '<option value="' + value.name + '">' + value.name + "</option>";
          }
        }
      });
      $("#" + id).html(html_code);
    });
  }
```